# basename command in unix

Tags: unix

We use base name command to know the file name usinf below script:

```
basename $0
```

Ho `$0` is interpreted as file name in this command, I observed that `$1` is not a correct command. Please help me in understanding this command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$0` contains the first element of argv in a bash script, which is the path to the executed script.